# Is there a programmatic way to retrieve notifications from JIRA without going through email?

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am working on a Python bot to sync a bunch of stuff for me from my JIRA instance on a regular basis. I don't want to be continuously polling a list of known JIRA keys looking for changes.

Ideally I would want the bot to add itself as a watcher to these JIRA issues and then occasionally poll the bot account's notification queue to see if there's anything new to sync. I did see the API docs on adding watchers. That seems trivial. However, I couldn't find anything about how to request the list of notifications from those watched issues without having to have JIRA email you the notification and then polling an email mailbox instead. Is there a way to just make a call from the Python API asking for a list of notifications?

Note: Using webhooks for this is not possible for me due to the instance's configuration restrictions.

Comment: Have you tried the JIRA community - https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/qa-p/jira-questions

Comment: I cross-posted the question but after a quick look it would seem like I would be more likely to get a programmatic focused answer to my question here.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative maybe you could retrieve the issues using a JQL. For example this JQL retrieve all issues updated in the last two days where I am a watcher.

```
updatedDate >= -2d and key in watchedIssues()
```

You can modify the updatedDate value to retrieve only the issues that have changed after your last sync.

Comment: I will give this a try and see how this works. My only worry about this approach is if my bot is on a 1 hour poll check, but then has some slight drift due to how much time it takes to do the sync job before going back to wait for an hour, I either need a way to check for dups in this call or to set my wait timer to account for job drift, maybe by doing its job on the top of the hour rather than actually waiting an hour.